# Tiny wrapper over winit Rust crate

Tags: rust

I have the following code where I try to create a warpper over winit crate. I want to wrap winit because I want to be able to replace it with minimal work in the future.

The code fails to compile, but I could not think of a way to make it work. If anyone has some pointers about how to keep the design I have in mind, but at the same time wrap winit please let me know.

Thank you!

`main.rs`

```rust
use crate::events::WindowResizeEvent;
use crate::window::Window;
use crate::window::WindowProps;

mod events;
mod window;

fn main() {
    let props = WindowProps {
        title: "Foo".to_string(),
        width: 1024,
        height: (1024.0 * 16.0 / 9.0) as usize,
    };

    let mut main_window = Window::new(props);

    main_window.set_on_window_resize(|event: WindowResizeEvent| {
        println!("{}", event);
    });

    main_window.run();
}
```

`events.rs`:

```rust
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter};

pub struct WindowResizeEvent {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}

impl Display for WindowResizeEvent {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        fmt.write_fmt(format_args!(
            "WindowResizeEvent[width = {}, height = {}]",
            self.width, self.height
        ))
    }
}

pub struct WindowCloseEvent;

impl Display for WindowCloseEvent {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        fmt.write_str("WindowCloseEvent")
    }
}
```

and finally `window.rs`

```rust
use winit::{
    dpi::LogicalSize,
    event::{Event, WindowEvent},
    event_loop::{ControlFlow, EventLoop},
    window::WindowBuilder,
};

use crate::events::{WindowCloseEvent, WindowResizeEvent};

pub struct WindowProps {
    pub title: String,
    pub width: usize,
    pub height: usize,
}

pub struct Window {
    event_loop: EventLoop<()>,
    window: winit::window::Window,

    on_window_resize: Option<fn(WindowResizeEvent)>,
    on_window_close: Option<fn(WindowCloseEvent)>,
}

impl Window {
    pub fn new(props: WindowProps) -> Self {
        let event_loop = EventLoop::with_user_event();

        let window = WindowBuilder::new()
            .with_visible(false)
            .with_title(&props.title)
            .with_inner_size(LogicalSize::new(props.width as f32, props.height as f32))
            .build(&event_loop)
            .expect("Unable to create window");

        Self {
            event_loop,
            window,
            on_window_resize: None,
            on_window_close: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn set_on_window_resize(&mut self, f: fn(WindowResizeEvent)) {
        self.on_window_resize = Some(f);
    }

    pub fn run(&self) {
        self.event_loop
            .run(move |event, _, control_flow| match event {
                Event::WindowEvent { event, .. } => match event {
                    WindowEvent::Resized(physical_size) => {
                        if let Some(on_window_resize) = self.on_window_resize.clone() {
                            on_window_resize(WindowResizeEvent {
                                width: physical_size.width,
                                height: physical_size.height,
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    WindowEvent::CloseRequested => {
                        if let Some(on_window_close) = self.on_window_close.clone() {
                            on_window_close(WindowCloseEvent);
                        }

                        *control_flow = ControlFlow::Exit;
                    }
                    _ => (),
                },

                _ => (),
            });
    }
}
```

I want that abstraction layer over winit because I like it more and maybe at some point I want to replace winit with something else and I don't want to change all the places that may use a window.

Now when I try to compile this I get this error and I can't find a way to make it work:

```
error[E0759]: `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
  --> ghost-sandbox/src/window.rs:49:18
   |
47 |       pub fn run(&self) {
   |                  ----- this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
48 |           self.event_loop
49 |               .run(move |event, _, control_flow| match event {
   |  __________________^
50 | |                 Event::WindowEvent { event, .. } => match event {
51 | |                     WindowEvent::Resized(physical_size) => {
52 | |                         if let Some(on_window_resize) = self.on_window_resize.clone() {
...  |
69 | |                 _ => (),
70 | |             });
   | |_____________^ ...is captured here...
   |
note: ...and is required to live as long as `'static` here
  --> ghost-sandbox/src/window.rs:49:14
   |
49 |             .run(move |event, _, control_flow| match event {
   |              ^^^

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0759`.
error: could not compile `ghost-sandbox`
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to move self into a [function](https://docs.rs/winit/0.24.0/winit/event_loop/struct.EventLoop.html#method.run) that requires all captured references to last for the `'static` lifetime (i.e. until the end of the program)

You can solve this by either passing self by value into the `Window::run()` function or making sure that self lives until the end of the program by adding a `'static` annotation to the `Window::run()` function e.g.

```
pub fn run(&'static self) { ...
```

However, if you do go with the `'static` lifetime option, you might encounter another error because [run](https://docs.rs/winit/0.24.0/winit/event_loop/struct.EventLoop.html#method.run) requires pass-by-value for the `EventLoop` object.